# Adding php code after If statment

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm new to PHP, and I'm working on a random number game. If the user guesses the right number, he gets a point. However, I am having trouble giving the point to the user. This is the code that I have for the game:

```
:<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>result</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main"></div>

        <div id="enterNumber">

            <?php
            $number_actual = rand(1, 20);
            $number_guess = $_REQUEST["inputnumber"];
            echo "You chose: " . $number_guess . "<br />";
            echo "The random number is: " . $number_actual . "<br />";
            if ($number_guess == $number_actual)
                echo "You guessed <b>Correctly!</b>";


            elseif ($number_guess < $number_actual)
            {
                echo "You are too <b>Low</b>!";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "Try guessing again...";
                echo "<form>
                        <input type='text' name='inputnumber' />
                        <input type='submit' value='Guess' />
                    </form>";
            }
            elseif ($number_guess > $number_actual)
            {
                echo "You are too <b>High</b>!";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "Try guessing again...";
                echo "<form>
                        <input type='text' name='inputnumber' />
                        <input type='submit' value='Guess' />
                    </form>";
            }
            ?>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is the code that gives the user a point, but I am getting a problem adding them together!

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE username='$username'");

$insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `points` = (`points` + 1) WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";

mysql_query($insert); 


header('location: succes.php');
}
}
?>
```

When I tried to add them, I did it like this:

```
<?php

$number_actual = rand(1, 20);
$number_guess = $_REQUEST["inputnumber"];
echo "You chose: " . $number_guess . "<br />";
echo "The random number is: " . $number_actual . "<br />";
if ($number_guess == $number_actual)
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE username='$username'");

$insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `points` = (`points` + 1) WHERE `username` = '" . $username . "'";

mysql_query($insert);


header('location: succes.php');
}

echo "You guessed <b>Correctly!</b>";


elseif ($number_guess<$number_actual)
{
echo "You are too <b>Low</b>!";
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
echo "Try guessing again...";
echo "<form>
            <input type='text' name='inputnumber' />
            <input type='submit' value='Guess' />
        </form>";
}
elseif ($number_guess>$number_actual)
{
    echo "You are too <b>High</b>!";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Try guessing again...";
    echo "<form>
            <input type='text' name='inputnumber' />
            <input type='submit' value='Guess' />
        </form>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I believe you may be having an issue with your query, try escaping the variable with {$username} in the query.

Comment: Also, you could just '".$username."'

Comment: I've never used `rand()`, but won't it generate a new random number everytime you reload the page (i.e. whenever the form is used) - and so the `actual_number` on their 2nd guess will be different than on their 1st guess

Comment: @ChrisW Yes. This is the game... Guess the number that will be generated.

Comment: BTW, OP should really learn how to debug, or he's going to have a bad time.

Comment: I want to point out that your code is vulnerable to XSS and SQL Injection. I know you are newbie, but try to find out something about web application security.

Comment: But then there's no point with your "too high" or "too low" statements, because when they guess another number, the page will reload, and a different random number will have been generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you placed the `echo "You guessed <b>Correctly!</b>";` between the if and the elseif. Should be:

```
<?php
                $number_actual = rand (1,20);
                $number_guess = $_REQUEST["inputnumber"];
                echo "You chose: " . $number_guess . "<br />";
                        echo "The random number is: " . $number_actual . "<br />";
                                if ($number_guess==$number_actual) { // you forgot this curly brace
                                   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE username='$username'");

    $insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `points` = (`points` + 1) WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";

     mysql_query($insert); 

    echo "You guessed <b>Correctly!</b>"; // this was placed inbetween the if and the elseif

    header('location: succes.php');
    }
```

Comment: i'm getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\games\result.php on line 29 (the one under header)

Comment: it's because you have another syntax error. you forgot to open the if statement with a curly brace. see my edit

Comment: Thanks, it worked;) need to wait 4 min to accept it

Comment: i noticed a problem... it seems like the insert code dont read. it doesnt add 1 to any of my feilds in users

Answer (score 0):

There are compilation issues in your code because of `unbalanced`}`` `. Always try to indent your code. Depending on the IDE you are using you can ``auto-indent` your code (By the way, I am using TextMate):

```
header('location: succes.php');
}
```

The `}` is not needed, so probabaly you forgot the `{`, so your code might be like this:

```
if ($number_guess==$number_actual) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE username='$username'");

    $insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `points` = (`points` + 1) WHERE `username` = '".$username."'";

    mysql_query($insert); 
    header('location: succes.php');
    echo "You guessed <b>Correctly!</b>";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, you wrong!</b>";
}
```

As soon as you try and indent your code you will find lots of issues yourself. And please do not pass user entered data to MySQL directly, or you might be a victim of `SQL INJECTION`. For that reason, please rewrite your query like this:

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'");

    $insert = "UPDATE `users` SET `points` = (`points` + 1) WHERE `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'";
```